# Download RDS & Image files from SSRS Server with PowerShell

Tags: sql-server, powershell, reporting-services, ssrs-2000

We have a SQL Server 2000 SSRS Server which cannot run many of the scripts I have found on the internet to retrieve Report Data Sources (RDS File) and Image Files (PNG, GIF). I have used PowerShell to download all the relevant RDL files as a batch but I also require the remaining images and datasources.

I use the following for displaying the contents of the ReportServer -

```
$ReportServerUri = "<ReportServerURL>/Reportserver/ReportService.asmx";
$Proxy = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri $ReportServerUri -Namespace SRS.ReportingService2000 -UseDefaultCredential ;
$itemProxy = $Proxy.ListChildren("/", $true) | select Name, Type, Path | Where-Object {$_.type -ne "Folder"};
```

I can view the RDS files through Powershell, but what method can I use to download them?